# PHP Color the lowest price in a table

Tags: php, colors, html-table, price

I try to insert 7 price values into a table and color the lowest price. I don't know where to place `$lowestprice`. I'm aware it's poor code, but it worked until I try to add a color.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++){
    ${"price".$i} = preg_replace($regexp, $match, ${"rawprice".$i});
        if (preg_match('/'.$article.'/i', ${"stock".$i}))
        {
            $list[$i] =  ${"price".$i};
            $lowestprice = min($list);
            if (preg_match('/^'.$lowestprice.'/i', ${"price".$i}))
            {
                echo ${"url".$i}." class=\"lowestprice\">".${"price".$i}." €</a></td>"; // lowest price in color with css
            }
            else
            {
                echo ${"url".$i}." class=\"price\">".${"price".$i}." €</a></td>";
            }                   
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td>Out of stock</td>";
        }
}
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting seems to have found a typo in you `echo` lines.  After the class name you have an extra double-quote.

Comment: seems like you're probably confusing PHP syntax with jQuery `$` syntax. You need to concatenate here.

Comment: @David Thanx, post edited.

Comment: *"but it worked until I try to add a color"* - Color, what color? As I said, your code resembles jQuery syntax.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I use CSS to modify the color with class="lowestprice"

Comment: Why are you not using arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do not use `${"string".$i}` type variables. It is great that it works, sure, but if you are working on data that seems to follow an array structure, just use an array. Less clutter, less drama, everyone happy.

$rawprice should be an array containing 7 integers with 7 prices in cents. Then you would do something like this:

```
$lowestPrice = min( $rawPrice );

for( $i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++ ) {
  if( inStock( $article[$i] ) ) {
    $price = str_replace( ".", ",", (string) ($rawPrice[$i] / 100 ) );

    if( $rawPrice[$i] == $lowestPrice ) {
      $class = "lowestprice";
    } else {
      $class = "price";
    }

    echo "<td><a href=\"{$url[$i]}\" class=\"{$class}\">{$price} €</a></td>";
  } else {
    echo "<td>Out of stock</td>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your help, it works better!